# jQuery AJAX submit by hotkeys

Tags: jquery, ajax, hotkeys

I'm trying to set "Ctrl+Enter" to execute function `update`:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e, id){
    var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey) {
        update(id);
    }
}
function update(id) {
    var title = $("#title"+id).val();
    var content = $("#content"+id).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {
                aid: id,
                title: title,
                content: content,
            },
            beforeSend : function(){
                alert(content);
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#view"+id).html(data);
            },

        });  
}
```

HTML part:

```
<input type="text" id="title<?php echo $id ?>" >
<textarea id="content<?php echo $id ?>" ></textarea>
```

It works with click event, but keypress. I tested with the above beforeSend and it returned `undefined`. What makes variable `content` become `undefined`? How could I fix it?

Comment: Take a look at my `EDIT 1` and it should solve your problem!

Comment: to get the id of the target, `e.target.id`. Though I'm not sure why do you do the concat like `$("#content"+id).val();`

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot PHP part in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a small, working example for you:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event)
  {
      var currKey=0,e=e||event; 
      currKey=e.keyCode||e.which||e.charCode;

      if (!( currKey == 13 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19))
        {
            return true; 
        }    
      event.preventDefault();       
      alert("Ctrl + Enter was pressed"); // Replace this with your update(id);
      return false;
  });
```

Focus on *input* field in the following example and try pressing `Ctrl+Enter` to see it in action.

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u2qUf/)

#### EDIT 1:

What made your `content` variable *undefined* is that its *scope*. You explicitly say `var content` and make its scope local, while trying to access it from another function.

Replace `var content` with `content` and you will get what you want!

**Explanation:**

> JavaScript has two scopes: global and local. A variable that is
> declared outside a function definition is a global variable, and its
> value is accessible and modifiable throughout your program. A variable
> that is declared inside a function definition is local. It is created
> and destroyed every time the function is executed, and it cannot be
> accessed by any code outside the function. JavaScript does not support
> block scope (in which a set of braces {. . .} defines a new scope),
> except in the special case of block-scoped variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally found the problem. Variable `id` had not been passed in this function `document.onkeydown = function(e, id)`. How could fix it? Thanks again.

Comment: I've solved it. After reading your answer, I see that var `id` is global. And I don't need to pass it in this function. So I just removed param `id`, `document.onkeydown = function(e)`.